# map: Bad Ptr even if the key was found

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map inside struct:

```
struct amountOfDist
{
        int time;
        vector<int> distVector;
        map<string,int> pairsMap;
};
amountOfDist m_tempDistStruct;
```

when the code runs, it crushes when I try to find a value:

```
if(m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap.find("(1,2)")->second != 1)
{
       ...
}
```

I tried to isolate the command by:

```
map<string,int>::iterator it;
it = m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap.find("(1,2)");
```

and I get `padptr`. But when I put break point on the line:

```
it = m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap.find("(1,2)");
```

I can see that the map hols all the keys and values (the correct ones) and the key (1,2) exists.

Why does the `find` command returns `badptr`?

I will be happy for guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're doing looks fine to me. The key must somehow not actually exist the way you think it does. Are the brackets different? Is there a space after the comma in the key in the map?

Comment: Have you tried to check the returned iterator against `m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap.end()` ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: effect not reproducible, works both for gcc and clang

Comment: The key is clearly not in the map, even though it appears to be so. Must be a space or subtle character difference.

Comment: It sounds like the map itself is broken, but it's impossible to guess how that would have happened.

Comment: How are you adding values to the map? Can you show us what exactly the debugger gives you?

Answer (score 1):

If the map really does contain the key you're looking for, then your code should work; something else has gone horribly wrong if it doesn't. However, the code is rather fragile, since it will give undefined behaviour if the key is missing.

You have to check whether `find` succeeded before dereferencing it; if it fails, then it returns a past-the-end iterator which isn't dereferencable. Alternatively, use `[]` which will insert a new element if it was missing.

So safer versions are:

```
// use find and check it exists
auto found = map.find(key);
if (found != map.end() && found->second != 1)

// use [] to insert if it doesn't exist
if (map[key] != 1)
```

If neither of these work, or you're absolutely sure that the key must exist, then we'll need to see a [complete test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to figure out what's going wrong with the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I get totally correct behavior. So I am pretty sure that the value you're looking for is not in the `map`.

```
amountOfDist m_tempDistStruct;

m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap["(1,2)"] = 10;

if  (m_tempDistStruct.pairsMap.find("(1,2)")->second == 10)
{
    cout << "GOT HERE!" << endl;
}
```

The above code snippet adds `"(1,2)" => 10` to the map, then finds it just fine. I suspect the key in your map is subtly different to what you think it is.